# What is claimable and what is not?

Tags: professionalism, management, human-resources, expenses

I work in Michigan, USA, and a while ago me and my manager attended a conference in a different state, which was related to our job. And I forgot my suit jacket there on the chair when we left.

Earlier yesterday, we brought up the story with someone from outside the company (We were laughing about a similar story) where that someone asked "*And did you expense it?*"

I did not ask my employer to buy me a new jacket when it happened, as I don't think me forgetting the jacket is a reasonable claim, and I am not planning to claim it now.

There was no chance to go back and get it when I mentioned I forgot my jacket right when we arrived back to the hotel, and they said they are sorry that it happened.

But that made me wonder, was it claimable? And is there a standard for what is claimable and what is not?

Comment: `was it claimable` what did your boss say? Or company policy? I'm not sure how this can be answered without asking your company.

Comment: Probably not. It wasn't a work jacket and you forgot it. Sounds like your colleague made a bad "joke"

Comment: @enderland There was no chance to go back and get it when I mentioned I forgot my jacket right when we arrived back to the hotel, and they said they are sorry that it happened.

Comment: A piece of clothing like a suit jacket that can be worn as normal clothing is not normally deductible. It needs to be identifiably industry-related attire, like a uniform. Your company might expense you; however, absent that; I think the IRS would deny it.

Comment: Have you considered contacting the organisers or venue to see if they have the jacket and whether you can collect it / they can send it to you? Can't lose much by trying. I suppose it depends how long ago "a while ago" is.

Comment: @Dukeling "_It was not possible_" even when we were there. organizers left to a different city right away

Comment: It's not the organizers, it's the venue.  Did the venue disappear?  It may be sitting in their lost-and-found waiting for a phone call.  Fair chance the other person wasn't recommending that, but was wondering if it would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expense policies are company specific and may be different at different ranks in the company. I have never worked anywhere in 40 years (Fortune 500 companies, government agencies, small companies, medium companies, contractor shops, etc. ) though where this would have been a claimable expense.

Comment: +1 for this. Normally expenses are things such as required equipment or for travel purposes